# Are there any ethical or legal issues when printing large texts from primary sources?

Tags: citations, ethics, copyright, legal-issues

I am writing a secondary History textbook. It is quite nearly done, but I am required to integrate some primary source materials, such as diaries, log entries, letters, etc.

- The textbook spans the 1200s to the 1920s, so I believe *any* primary source materials should be free of copyright. The texts would be published in either the USA or Mexico most often.
- Since primary sources can be difficult to find, often being in rare, really old books in far-away libraries, or being they are written in an ancient form of a language I cannot read, I'll rely on modern translations and academic books containing excerpts and mentions of these primary sources to help track down suitable example passages.
- Since the recent books have copyright, I won't copy from their verbatim quotes. Instead these modern books will just serve to help me track down the original sources, from which I can directly copy, or use a translation service. So the text isn't at all copies from the modern source.

Given the above steps, are there any professional or legal concerns?

Is there a need to cite the modern books even I went direct to the original source for the actual excerpt?

Comment: You are asking for legal advice about copyright. This is outside the scope of this forum. You need to talk to the publisher or your textbook and, potentially, their lawyers.

Comment: Maybe try asking here? https://law.stackexchange.com/